# EE6 Transcribe Add-on Step-By-Step Guide?

Tags: transcribe, ee6, translation

Important question from the jump since I may have terribly misunderstood something:

Does "Transcribe" on EEHarbor automatically translate content or do you have to manually translate the words and copy-paste them/create variables yourself?

EDIT: Yeah, there is no translation feature in this add-on. I'll likely be looking at Publisher which does explicitly offer auto-translation.

<strike>That aside, I find myself at a loss in implementing this add-on. **I've already read through the documentation, but I need my hand held here in a major way.**</strike>

I've installed it, created the default language English (en) and second language Spanish (es). I created a test page in English, and related it to a test page in Spanish. I created a template:

```
{exp:transcribe:entries channel="general"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {page_content}

{/exp:transcribe:entries}
```

And I can view both of my test entries using that template. However, the content is 1:1 - both in English. Which is not what I was expecting from: "Transcribe handles everything from word/phrase translation to channel entry translations..."

This is a pre-existing site with MANY existing entries. Transcribe's documentation states it has a work-around for that scenario, which only links to the Tag Reference page. And at least at the moment, the terminology used on that page is so vague and circular that I can't make heads or tails of what I'm supposed to use - the same general framework as what I have above? Or do I use {exp:transcribe:language} or {exp:transcribe:translate} and does that mean I need to create 2 templates for each language or just 1? Please please just give a Step 1, Step 2, Step 3.

Or, I guess, if my initial assumption is wrong - what's everyone using to translate their sites first?

Answer (score 0):

Transcribe does not translate. It is more of a multilingual content management addon.

It gives you the means of adding languages to a site, and fields to store said language content. It does require the site owner to input the translated content.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing...  I feel a bit misled, though glad this was included in an add-on bundle and I didn't purchase it separately. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: For machine/AI translation you might try JCOGS Auto-Translate: https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/ee-auto-translate

Comment: Oh, that's a lot cheaper than Publisher, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: Publisher does not auto-translate either. Like Transcribe, Publisher is more of a multilingual manager, not a means of auto-translation.

Before you dismiss either one, just be aware there's power in both, as they offer an admin user interface for language manuage, template tags, variables. And there's a *lot* of website content elements where AI translation can fail: Buttons, links, "Submit," "Login," etc - those can be variables managed by Transcribe or Publisher.

Comment: Ah, slight correction. As of Feb 2024 I believe Publisher also supports DeepL: https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher